# スライドアウトでスライドが入れ替わり、若干ズームアウトしつつ画像が表示されるスライダーの制作

Tags: html, jquery, css

以下のようなスライダーの制作をしたいのですが、良いプラグインなどご存知の方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか。自作を試みたもののさっぱり出来上がりませんでした。

- **スライドアウト**でスライドが入れ替わる
- **若干ズームアウトしつつ**画像が表示される

参考サイト：[スライダー参考サイト](https://maquillage.shiseido.co.jp/)

上記２点以外の要素の実装はしません。
スクラッチが難しそうなので可能であればプラグインを改変する程度で済ませたいと考えています。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vegas.jsはどうでしょうか？
https://vegas.jaysalvat.com/

ドキュメントにあるslideLeftなどのトランジションとkenburnsアニメーションを組み合わせると良いかと思います。
動きが気に入らなければ自分でcssアニメーションを書くこともできます(custom transitions, custom animations参照)
http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/transitions/

Comment: こちらのスライドで実装できそうです！デモを拝見しましたが動きも参考サイトに近く、またCSS調整を自分で行うことができる点からこのプラグインで実現できそうです。実際に実現できたらまた報告させていただきます。

Comment: トランジションslideLeft、アニメーションkenburnsに設定し、トランジションslideLeftに関するCSSを以下のようにすることで実現できました。
.vegas-transition-slideLeft {
          -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
                  transform: translateX(0%);
                  z-index: 190;
      }

      .vegas-transition-slideLeft-in {
          -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
                  transform: translateX(0%);
                  z-index: 200;
      }

      .vegas-transition-slideLeft-out {
          -webkit-transform: translateX(200%);
                  transform: translateX(200%);
                  z-index: 200;

Comment: よかったです！ちなみにですが、transformは大抵のwebkit環境でベンダープレフィックス取れてるので、-webkit-transformはいらないかもですね。